# How did Carnot come up with the idea of Carnot Engine being the most efficient engine?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I am not asking the proof of why the Carnot Engine is the most efficient engine.

I wish to know the history of the development of idea of the most efficient engine. I wish to know how Carnot came up with the idea of Carnot Engine being the most efficient engine? and how did he know that it was the most efficient engine?

Answer (score 2):

Carnot wanted to answer two questions about the operation of heat engines: "Is the work available from a heat source potentially unbounded?" and "Can heat engines in principle be improved by replacing the steam with some other working fluid or gas?" He attempted to answer these in a memoir, published as a popular work in 1824 when he was only 28 years old. It was entitled *Réflexions sur la Puissance Motrice du Feu* ("Reflections on the Motive Power of Fire"). The book was plainly intended to cover a rather wide range of topics about heat engines in a rather popular fashion; equations were kept to a minimum and called for little more than simple algebra and arithmetic, except occasionally in the footnotes, where he indulged in a few arguments involving some calculus. He discussed the relative merits of air and steam as working fluids, the merits of various aspects of steam engine design, and even included some ideas of his own regarding possible improvements of the practical nature. The most important part of the book was devoted to an abstract presentation of an idealized engine that could be used to understand and clarify the fundamental principles that are generally applied to all heat engines, independent of their design.